# Diagnosing MobileServiceInvalidOperationException

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I'm calling an Azure Mobile Service from a Windows Phone 8 emulator.
Sometimes I receive a `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` with no InnerException property. In Fiddler, I see the response contains only 400 - Bad Request. No further details.

How do I diagnose these problems? Are there any server-side logging tools on Azure Mobile Services to aid me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I'll share it with you in case another Azure Mobile Services beginner is looking for this.
On the Azure management portal, go to your mobile service. There is a "Logs" tab which records server-side errors. That's all I needed:

[image]